# Use the ID attribute of a clicked element as a paramter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of anchor tags that when clicked I would like the value of their ID attribute to be send to the parameter of a stored procedure.  Everything works fine except I don't know how to make the second argument of the `AddWithValue` method of the `Parameters` property of the `SqlCommand` accept whatever is clicked instead of hard coding it.  The results are read from a simple stored procedure and then put into a grid view control

markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQueryEachExample._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">




    <asp:HyperLink ID="Xtown" runat="server">Xtown</asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Ztown" runat="server">Ztown</asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Atown" runat="server">Atown</asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Bburg" runat="server">Bburg</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="stateGridView">

</asp:GridView>     

</asp:Content>
```

code behind

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace jQueryEachExample
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //let the connection string be read from the web.config file
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;

            //create a connection
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                //open connection
                conn.Open();
                //create the SqlCommand object
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spFindCityInfo", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityName",this argument needs to be the id attribute of the link was that clicked
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityName", Xtown.ID);//Xtown.ID is what needs to be whatever is clicked
                //create a reader
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    stateGridView.DataSource = reader;
                    stateGridView.DataBind();
                }


            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming these buttons are going to be created in a more generic fashion, e.g. within a repeater or something.

I would recommend changing the `HyperLinks` to `LinkButtons` so that you can access the `OnClick` event and also putting the data access code into a method Then do something like: -

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Xtown" runat="server" OnClick="lnkButtonClick">Xtown</asp:LinkButton>

private void UpdateDB(string id)
{
     string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
     {
        //*snip*
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityName", id);//ID from clicked control 
     }
}


protected void lnkButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string id = ((LinkButton)sender).ClientID;
     UpdateDB(id);
}
```

This answers the question as it was asked with regards to passing ID attribute as a parameter to the stored proc.

However, i would tweak this instead to use `CommandArguments` like so:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Xtown" runat="server" OnClick="lnkButtonClick" CommandArgument="Xtown">Xtown</asp:LinkButton>
```

And access it in a similar way to the clientid:

```
protected void lnkButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string args = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
     UpdateDB(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CommandArgument` of a `LinkButton`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding you should use LinkButton instead of hyperlink and handle the click event of each LinkButton. Put your SQL code in a separate parameterized method and pass the LinkButton Control Id from each event as an argument.